# Quiero insertar en un Entry lo traido con un SELECT en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Quiero poder insertar el dato que traigo con la query del SELECT, dentro del Entry. alguien me puede ayudar?. Adjunto código.

```
def seleccionar_producto(self, event):

    self.menu_productosID.current(self.menu_productos.current())
    id_prod = self.menu_productosID.get()

    # Conexión

    db = sqlite3.connect('PDVdamoonplay.db')
    conexion = db.cursor()

    conexion.execute('SELECT stock.precio_venta FROM stock JOIN productos ON stock.producto = productos.id WHERE stock.producto = ?', [id_prod])
    db_rows = conexion.fetchone()
    print(db_rows)
    self.entry_PrecioU = []
    self.entry_PrecioU.insert(0, db_rows)
```

Comment: Cual sería el problema? Sin un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) o una explicación de lo que está pasando, no hay manera de que lo sepamos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por preguntar, pero ya le encontré la solución, me habia olvidado de dar la respuesta.

Comment: De nada! Me alegro de que hayases la solución c: